# How to check min/max length at multiple points in regex

Tags: python, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate an email address. The username, domain, and TLD must be digits and letters only, and between 3-20 in length. I've got that as

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}`

So, when I want to use that to check all 3 portions of the email, I would think to do it as follows:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}\+@[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}\+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}`

However, this does not validate. Is there a way to validate the min/max length once, instead of at 3 different points?

The email I'm attempting to validate is: `testuser@testdomain.com`

I'm writing this using python3 and the data is read in from a .csv

Comment: Your `\+`s require `+`s to be in the match.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So just `+` instead of `\+` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with them? Just leave them out entirely, I think?

Comment: I misread the docs on what `+` totally a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '+' are causing the emails to not match *unless* the '+' are in that position:

This is what you want:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}`

To help write regex this site is a life saver:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: I misunderstood what the `+` actually does in regex. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

`([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20})@([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20})[.]([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20})`

using https://regex101.com

Comment: The extra parenthesis are unnecessary

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a timeout error on regex101.com? Works for me with the python regex flavor

Comment: They are not necessary but they do make it more obvious which each capturing group is.